# $x \ge 0, z \ge 0, xz \ge y^2$ for symmetric $2 \times 2$ positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am told that the positive semidefinite cone in $\mathbf{S}^2$ is

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbf{S}^2_+ \iff x \ge 0, \ \ \ z \ge 0, \ \ \ xz \ge y^2,$$

where $S^2_+$ is the set of symmetric $2 \times 2$ positive semidefinite matrices.

I suspect that the conditions $x \ge 0, z \ge 0, xz \ge y^2$ comes from the fact that the matrix is positive semidefinite, but can someone please make it clear why this is required for a positive semidefinite matrix?

[This definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix) is the one I am using, but it doesn't say anything explicit about the values of the elements of the matrix.

Comment: This is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is real symmetric and positive semi-definite, you can write it as

$$X = B^TB$$

(where B isn't unique -- $B^T$ could be for instance lower triangular as in Cholesky.  But for any valid choice of $B$ the following arguments hold.)
Let $B=  \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf b_1 \vert \mathbf b_2
\end{bmatrix}$. Then,

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_1 & \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 \\ \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 & \mathbf b_2^T \mathbf b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \big \Vert \mathbf b_1\big \Vert_2^2  & \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 \\ \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 & \big \Vert \mathbf b_2\big \Vert_2^2  \end{bmatrix}$$ 
By Cauchy-Schwarz, this implies
$$y^2 = (\mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2)^2 \leq \big \Vert \mathbf b_1\big \Vert_2^2  \cdot \big \Vert \mathbf b_2\big \Vert_2^2  = x \cdot z.$$

Comment: Where did $X = B^TB$ come from?

Comment: Look up either (1) what it means to take a square root of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix or (2) Cholesky Factorization.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Statement interesting. But this has that $A = LL^*$, where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix with real and positive diagonal entries, and $L^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $L$; is that what $X = B^TB$ is?

Comment: right -- of course $L^T = L^*$ since you are working with real scalars

Comment: "When $A$ is symmetric, the factorization may be written $A = LL^T$." I missed this part in the article. But why is this different to your $X = B^TB$?

Comment: Dom assign $B:= L^T$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What does it mean to have $\mathbf b_1 \vert \mathbf b_2$?

Comment: This is a matrix blocked by columns

Comment: How does that turn into $B^TB = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_1 & \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 \\ \mathbf b_1^T \mathbf b_2 & \mathbf b_2^T \mathbf b_2 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: this is the definition of matrix multiplication.  Practice computing these dot products yourself

Comment: But how is the product $$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf b_1 \\ \hline \mathbf b_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf b_1 \vert \mathbf b_2
\end{bmatrix}$$ performed? Don't we have to know what the elements of $\mathbf b_1$ and $\mathbf b_2$ are?

Comment: I ask that you show some work for computing the product  $X = B^T B= \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf b_1^T \\ \hline \mathbf b_2^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf b_1 \vert \mathbf b_2 \end{bmatrix}$   i.e. explicitly write out the value of some component in $X$ in terms of dot products of values in from B.  After computing a few examples for yourself the result should, eventually, be very clear.

Comment: Oh, as $\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf b_1^T \\ \hline \mathbf b_2^T \end{bmatrix}$, with the transpose of the vectors in the matrix, I now see the result. So the vectors $\mathbf{b}_1^T$ and $\mathbf{b}_2^T$ are blocks of rows vectors (since they're now transposed), right?

Comment: Yes— This is the basic “blocking and tackling” of matrix multiplication (with a pun intended)

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of $X$ are given by $$\left|\begin{bmatrix} x-\lambda & y \\ y & z-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\right|=0\implies \lambda^2-(x+z)\lambda+(xz-y^2)=0.\\
\implies\lambda=\frac{(x+z)\pm\sqrt{(x+z)^2-4(xz-y^2)}}{2}.$$
A symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are nonnegative.
\begin{align}
\lambda\geq0 \iff & x+z\geq \sqrt{(x+z)^2-4(xz-y^2)}\geq 0\\
\iff& (x+z)^2 \geq (x+z)^2-4(xz-y^2) \text{ and } x+z\geq 0\\
\iff & xz\geq y^2\geq 0 \text{ and } x+z\geq 0\\
\iff & xz \geq y^2,\; x\geq 0 \text{ and } z\geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: Is $\lambda^2-(x+z)+(xz-y^2)$ supposed to be the determinant? If so, then shouldn't it be $(x - \lambda)(z - \lambda) - y^2 = xz - x\lambda -z\lambda + \lambda^2 - y^2$?

Comment: That was typo. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: What imposed the $x + z \ge 0$ condition in the second line?

Comment: We are allowed to square both sides of inequality only if $x+z\geq 0$. Clearly, when $x+z<0$, the inequality doesn't hold. I have added this point to the answer.